# Ruby ActiveRecord: DEPRECATION WARNING: Relation#find_in_batches with finder options is deprecated

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm implementing Model.find_each as mentioned here:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches

but I'm getting this error message:

```
Ruby ActiveRecord: DEPRECATION WARNING: Relation#find_in_batches with finder options is deprecated. Please build a scope and then call find_in_batches on it instead.
```

for this code:

```
Person.find_each(start: start_index, limit: limit) do |person|
```

I'm pretty much following the code given in the documentation so I'm a little puzzled. Is this code correct and, if not, what's the fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `limit: limit` for `batch_size: limit`

**EDIT**

Since you need a limit and your batch is based on id, i think you can do something like:

```
Person.where("id < ?", (start_index + limit)).find_each(start: start_index) do |person|
```

Comment: But that just changes the batch size. I want to limit the number of records returned to `limit`

Comment: In the link that you post say: 1.3.1.1 Options for find_each

The find_each method accepts most of the options allowed by the regular find method, except for :order and :limit, which are reserved for internal use by find_each.

Two additional options, :batch_size and :start, are available as well.

Comment: Yes, missed that point about :limit being reserved for internal use. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get exactly the issue but I think you can just write this:

```
Person.offset(start_index).limit(limit).find_each(batch_size: NUMBER) do |person|
```

`find_each` is just a replacement for `each`, it's the last thing you should do on a query and you should use it only to choose how many results will be loaded in memory (`batch_size`).

For offsets/limits you should use the *usual* query API.
**Important:** Notice that `find_each` has nothing to do with `find`, `find_each` replaces `each`, which should be used to loop over records, not to find/filter/what else.

Also, is clearly written in the guide:

> The find_each method accepts most of the options allowed by the
>   regular find method, except for :order and :limit, which are reserved
>   for internal use by find_each.

So you can't use `:limit`. In any case I think there is something wrong in the guide: you should use `find_each` for looping, not for searching.

Notice also that `:start` is used to *restart at some point an interrupted job* (it's not directly and id like 2000, it's the 2000 element in a batch of 5000 for example), much like the docs states:

> By default, records are fetched in ascending order of the primary key,
>   which must be an integer. The :start option allows you to configure
>   the first ID of the sequence whenever the lowest ID is not the one you
>   need. This would be useful, for example, if you wanted to resume an
>   interrupted batch process, provided you saved the last processed ID as
>   a checkpoint.

**You should not use it to replace `offset` and `limit` methods from `ActiveRecord`**